# $f$ and $g$ are equal almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

I'm looking for an example of two functions that are equal almost everywhere, one of them is measurable but the other one is not (I think this is only possibly in a not-complete measure space).

I found the following example, but I don't underastand it very well:

Take a not-complete space $X$. Then there exists $V$ such that $V$ is not measurable and $V$ is contained in a set of measure zero. Consider $f=0$ and $g=\chi_V$. It is obvious that $f$ is measurable, while $g$ is not measurable. But I don't see why $f=g$ almost everywhere. If it is the case, then we would have that $\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\}=V$ is measurable and has meazure zero. Am I right? (But $V$ wasn't measurable...)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $V$ is contained in some set of measure zero (call it $U$).  Thus, we can say that $\{x: f(x) \neq g(x)\} = V \subset U$, which indeed means that they are equal all most everywhere, since they are equal "except on the set $U$, which is of measure $0$".